# How to remove controller name in REST design in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given a User resource, it goes like this

/user/:shortname

But how can the controller name be removed to get just

/:shortname

How can I declare this in routes.rb while keeping all CRUD functionality instant?

Updated: After reading [this](http://blog.peepcode.com/tutorials/2010/rethinking-rails-3-routes) I'm moving to Sinatra over Rails to handle this API-like design better.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, here. Do you mean `/users/:shortname`?

Comment: I'm sure this question has been asked at least 3 times before and I've answered one of them, but I cannot find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a custom match:

```
match ':shortname' => 'users#action'
```

Replace *action* in *users#action* with the name of the action that is supposed to receive the request. Just remember to place it in the appropriate order in your routes file. Rails looks at each line of your routes file starting at the top and selects the first matching route. ':shortname' would match any first-level path, including /users! So put it below any routes using a first-level path, which would include all of your resource routes. Here's an example:

```
resources :users
resources :posts
match '/blog' => 'posts#index'
match ':shortname' => 'users#action'
```

Comment: Yes I know that. But for some reason when I add all the CRUD actions it doesn't work. Also, is there a cleaner way to avoid declare each action for the same controller?

Answer (score 1):

In routes, you should be able to do something like

```
resource :users, :path => '/:shortname'
```

Try that out and `rake routes` to see if that comes out as expected.

Comment: That doesn't work. That basically just replace the controller name for /:shortname/:shortname.